# how to write iges file?

Tags: c#, file

I would like to be able to write the .iges file format using c#. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is this what you're talking about?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGES

Comment: yes i talk about that format only

Comment: Another open point in your question is: What is the source from what you will create such a file? A bitmap, svg, an API, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has [some good information on the IGES file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGES) which might be of use.

**[Edit]** There is [a commercially library](http://www.wiz-worx.com/products/wisl/wisl.htm) available which seems to be able to read and write IGES files.

Comment: You asked for help and didn't specify how far you'd got, so I thought this might help. Is there a specific aspect of writing these files that you're struggling with? Have you tried writing out some binary data as per the spec?

Comment: links are out of date, iges preservation society seems to be gone

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to buy the specification (see [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/fileformats-faq/part3/section-68.html)). Once you have the specs, you'll create one or more data structures that represents the contents of your file (always according to the specs). Then, it's just about filling the structure and writing to the file.

Comment: I'm using specs provided here. https://wiki.eclipse.org/IGES_file_Specification#Transformation_Matrix_.28Type_124.29 However I'm not sure how exactly is it processing the curves. Say I have an .igs file of only one B-spline surface. The only valid entity should be 128, which contains two knot vectors, weights, all control points, etc, that represents a B-spline surface. But in the iges file, it also writes lots of entity 126-rational B-spline curves and 102-composite curves, which seem unrelated/unnecessary to the surface. But once deleted, .igs became unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be very complex to try and write IGES.  I'm not sure what your input is, but  investigate using a 3d format converter such as [Okino NuGraf](http://www.okino.com/nrs/nrs.htm) to convert that input, whatever it is, to IGES.  There are lots and lots of pitfalls trying to write out those 3d formats...